# intersection of all maximal centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be non-abelian.

Let say $C_G(x)$ is maximal centralizer if $x\in G-Z(G)$ and there is no $g\in G-Z(G)$ such that $C_G(x)< C_G(g)$. Now let $C$ be the intersection of all maximal centralizer of $G$.

Clearly, $Z(G)\leq C$.

Is $C$ necessarily abelian ?

Comment: Since $C_G(1)=G$, the only maximal centralizer is $G$ itself.

Comment: Maybe you want to assume everything to be proper here (no idea if anything interesting happens, but at least it stops being trivial).

Comment: I had meant that centrilizer is proper. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several examples of order $128$ in which $C$ is not abelian, such as $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(128,71)$. In this example, the maximal centralizers are exactly the maximal subgroups, so $C = \Phi(G)$, and is not abelian.

I haven't thought about whether it is true in all finite $p$-groups that $C=\Phi(G)$.

Comment: can you tell me, what is the presentation of this group?

Comment: You can find it yourself using GAP.

Comment: @DerekHolt: $Z_2\times Q_8$ is counter example.

Comment: Really? I make it $C = Z_2 \times Z_2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: You had said that "I haven't thought about whether it is true in all finite $p$-groups that $C=\Phi(G)$." In $Z_2 \times Q_8$, $\Phi(G)=1\times Z_2$ and $C=Z_2\times Z_2$ as you wrote.

Comment: Oh I see -sorry, I thought you meant it was a counterexample to your original question!

Comment: @DerekHolt :  I had guessed. Derek I want ask one more question.I ecpect that $C\leq F(G)$ i.e $C$ is nilpotent. Is there any counter example ?